# Netrw: Can't Explore with scp?

Tags: netrw

I wish to use netrw `:Explore` on a remote server via ssh tunnelling, but can't manage to do it.

I can access the server perfectly fine using `ssh` and remotely edit files with vim:

```
vim scp://userid@hostname//path/to/filename
```

works fine for me. However when I try to work with directory the userid / hostname seems to go completely wrong:

```
vim scp://userid@hostname//path/to/directory/
```

is interpreted as `@userid@hostname` (not the usual `scp -q 'userid@hostname:/path/to/file'` I usually get with a file), so I get a permission denied (publickey,password).

What should I do to get access to the directory (or to use `:Explore`, the problem being the same).

Comment: What if you leave off the trailing slash? Interesting q

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. If I remove the trailing slash: `vim scp://userid@hostname//path/to/directory`
vim just create a new file.

Comment: Relevant thread: [How to troubleshoot SSH-related issues in Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38842/how-to-troubleshoot-ssh-related-issues)