# How to troubleshoot SSH-related issues?

Tags: ssh

**server A** (1.2.3.4): I'm accessing it every day, no issues:

- keys on the local machine are in `~/.ssh` (`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`)
- user "toraritte" is available on both machines
- starting and using Vim the following way:

  ```
  $ ssh-agent vim
  ```

  Inside Vim:

  ```
  :!ssh-add
  (enter pass-phrase => "identity added")

  :Lexplore scp://1.2.3.4//home/toraritte/
  ```

---

**server B** (5.6.7.8): just set up, `scp` & `ssh` works both outside and inside Vim, but `:Lexplore scp://` fails with `shell returned 255`. The setup is different too, but can't figure out the problem:

- Users are different (`toraritte` on local, `myadmin` on remote)
- Using a `.pem` file to which is not in the `~/.ssh` folder like so:

  ```
  # similar with scp
  ssh -i my.pem myadmin@5.6.7.8
  ```

Starting and using Vim:

```
$ ssh-agent vim
```

Inside Vim:

```
:!ssh-add my.pem
(no passphrase => "identity added")
```

Testing the shell:

```
:term

# on the terminal:
$ ssh myadmin@5.6.7.8                         #=> works
$ scp myadmin@5.6.7.8:/home/myadmin/test_file . #=> works
```

but

```
:Lexplore scp://myadmin@5.6.7.8//home/myadmin/
```

fails with `shell returned 255`, [which can mean a lot of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885748/ssh-script-returns-255-error).

So how can I troubleshoot this further?

---

**workaround**: Started [using Midnight Commander to access the remote machine's files](https://4sysops.com/archives/midnight-commander-remote-connect-via-shell-link-copy-files-over-ssh-and-sftp-link-using-fish-and-public-key-authentication/#attachment_1564128) for the time being, and [use Vim as an external editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16776/how-to-switch-the-editor-in-mc-midnight-commander-from-nano-to-mcedit/16782).

---

**update**: Thank you @MartinTournoij for constantly providing new tips!

1. > Does using `sftp://` work?

   No. This time there are no errors, only an empty side panel opens up.
2. > You can try adding `-v` to [`g:netrw_sftp_cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#g%3Anetrw_sftp_cmd) and/or [`g:netrw_scp_cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#g%3Anetrw_scp_cmd) and see if that shows anything; you can add it multiple times for more information

   This didn't work either. The only difference is that on the command line is now

   ```
   shell returned 255


   shell returned 255
   Press ENTER or type command to continue
   ```

   and the second `shell returned 255` will take longer to appear. I presume the output **is** more verbose, but it is not presented in Vim...
3. > Also noticed this bug: [Vim issue #11346](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11346) – not sure if it's related, but it might be?

   The `scp`/`sftp` operations in the issue certainly seem to be the same, but the error there is 1, so not sure either. Thank you for digging this up though! I will keep watching it for updates.

Comment: Does using `sftp://` work? scp and sftp use different protocols, and some defaults/settings changed last year. I think I've seen people have problems with this before.

Comment: Appreciate the tip, but `sftp://` isn't working either. It doesn't throw any errors, but simply opens an empty side window.

Comment: You can try adding `-v` to `g:netrw_sftp_cmd` and/or `g:netrw_scp_cmd` and see if that shows anything; you can add it multiple times for more information. Not sure if netrw displays that nicely though.

Comment: Also noticed this bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11346 – not sure if it's related, but it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously, the solution was almost the same as [the one for Midnight Commander explained in this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/midnight-commander-remote-connect-via-shell-link-copy-files-over-ssh-and-sftp-link-using-fish-and-public-key-authentication/#attachment_1564128):

> In Midnight Commander, unlike in SSH or SCP, you cannot pass the
> identity file with the `-i` parameter for public key authentication.
> Thus, you have to store the SSH configuration in your config file. The
> file is located in your home directory in `~/.ssh/config`.
>
> If the file does not exist, you can just edit with the nano editor and
> then make sure that only your user has access to it:
>
> ```
> chmod 600 config
> ```
>
> The config file should contain the location of your
> private SSH key, the corresponding username, and the hostname. In
> addition, you can configure the port and the alias you want to use to
> save some typing (`Host` command).
>
> ```
> Host yourHost
>     HostName 10.0.0.1
>     Port 2222
>     User ubuntu
>     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privatekey.key
> ```

To follow the article's example values, this is the command that kept failing for me,

```
:Lexplore scp://ubuntu@10.0.0.1:2222//home/ubuntu/
```

and I just needed to replace the `user@host:port` part with the `Host` section's value in the `~/ssh.config`

```
:Lexplore scp://yourHost//home/ubuntu/
```